# Secure storage of credentials for screen scraping

Tags: security, screen-scraping

I am writing an application which will take users credentials for a third party site so I can add value by screen scraping their account.

For this I need to be able to store credentials in a secure manner with a reversible crypto so I can get them in the clear again.

What is a secure (and easy) way of doing this for my MVP? Shall I just encrypt with AES and use a composite key (master secret + user account related salt).

Perhaps Vault from Hashicorp would suffice for this?

Asked another way. For the products that scrape your bank account, how do they store credentials?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

> Asked another way. For the products that scrape your bank account, how do they store credentials?

They don't scrape the account. They use an API from the bank's back end vendor or download an export file.

In any case, you absolutely don't want to be holding banking userid's/passwords. It's a staggering liability. If the account gets hacked, everybody will be looking at you to pay back the losses.

Comment: Incorrect - there are many vendors of software out there that do hold credentials and scrape the account. Was very much the case before Open Banking and APIs in Europe and probably still the case elsewhere.

Comment: I guess you would would have the user waive liability through T&C's. FWIW I am not working in the financial sector

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [CryptProtectData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptprotectdata) / [CryptUnprotectData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptunprotectdata) pair of functions. Maybe it can solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no safe way of storing their credentials. All the ways include you having the "master key" to be able to reverse the credentials into plain text, while all safe ways of storing authentication information uses one-way hashing (with salting!). [Never encrypt credentials, hash them](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41447/why-is-password-hashing-considered-so-important).

The only safe-ish way I can think of doing anything close to what you want, is to ask the users for their credentials at the moment of scraping, and pass that information on to the scraper without storing the information along the way. Make sure you do this over `https` or similar, and that your server is safe from memory inspection by other software running on the server, meaning you'd like to have full control of the entire data flow.

What this means is that you can only access the users data when the user is logged in to your service.

In short, I'd be very careful about this whole thing.